# How do I downgrade my gear type in openshift?

Tags: openshift

I've accidentally selected the large gear when I was creating my application in openshift. Is there a way to downgrade the gear type without actually recreating my app? Like from large to to medium or maybe even from large to small.highcpu.

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do have to recreate your app, however, there is an easy way to create a copy using the `--from-app` flag.

To change gear sizes, scaling, and/or deployment region you can use `rhc app create` to clone your existing application. The command below will create a complete copy of the original app and create a new, non-scalable version of the app using a small.highcpu gear in the default US region:

```
$ rhc app create <new_app_name> --from-app <existing_app_name> --no-scaling --gear-size small.highcpu
```

The command below will create a complete copy of the original app and create a new, scalable version of the app using medium gears in the Europe region:

```
$ rhc app create <new_app_name> --from-app <existing_app_name> --scaling --gear-size medium --region aws-eu-west-1
```

For more info on scaling and available gear sizes check out the OpenShift [Developer Portal](https://developers.openshift.com/en/overview-platform-features.html).

Comment: Your answer helped me. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't downgrade an existing gear. However you can use `rhc snapshot` feature to migrate your application easier to a smaller gear.

You can read about snapshot and restore in the documentation: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-backing-up-applications.html